# Is core data the solution?

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm working on an application which contains a photo album. When a photo from an album is tapped it pops up and shows the likes and comments it got as we have in Facebook. The information of likes and comments is fetched from the server. Do I need to store this information of likes/comments fetched from server in core data or simply use arrays for it. Please suggest?

Comment: why to use core data as you can directly fetch number of likes directly from graph api ?

Comment: I'm not using Facebook. I'm working for my own app. Can we use graph api in our app?

Comment: Why do you need to store likes/comments statically while it changes in real time?

Comment: @Thanh-NhonNGUYEN Because I need to show them with the Image that this image got e.g 50 likes and also I need to show who like the image. For this purpose, once I received the information from the server I need to store them in an array or some kind of database. I'm confused what to use?

Comment: Since you have to fetch the whole updated list likes/comments anyway, I don't think it's a good idea to store in a database but an array. Don't know if there's another caching method. Just like fb, it's not that users are always want to know the precise list of who liked and commented, it's the number of likes and comments that we have to concern. So I suggest you provide a method which returns only the total number of likes/comments of a photo for the sake of reduce data amount.

Comment: @Thanh-NhonNGUYEN Like fb I also need to show who liked and commented the photo. I'm now using an 3 separate arrays. 1. for total number of likes, 2. Who liked them, 3. for comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand exactly what you mean but here is my solution:

1. Create a class `Photo` which has

   1.1. `photoURL` as `NSString`

   1.2. `numberOfLikes` and `numberOfComments` as `NSInteger`.

   1.3. `arrayLikes` and `arrayComments` as `NSArray` of `NSString` for simplicity. If you want user to access other user's profile, you may think of create an another class `User`.
2. In runtime, use an `arrayPhotos` to contains all the downloaded Photos.
3. Whether you display your photos in a table or a collection view, just use `indexPath.row` to access each `Photo` in `arrayPhotos` and get the informations.

Comment: I have done exactly the same. Thanks a lot :)